# How to display the max and min values corresponding to each x-axis values in the scatterplot in Matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I get the `scatterplot` as follows:

```
x['hour_min'] = x['hour'].astype(str) + '_' + x['minute'].astype(str)
plt.subplots(figsize=(48, 8))
sns.scatterplot(x.hour_min, x.label)
plt.title('{}th label'.format(i+1))
plt.xlabel('hour_min')
plt.ylabel('label')
```

And I want to display the max and min values like this way:

[image]

It should show every max and min values corresponding to each value in the x-axis like the red part.
But I don't know to how to make it.
If not mind could anyone could help me?
Thanks in advances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could annotate the values as such:

```
vals = x.groupby('hour_min', as_index=False).agg({'label':[min,max]})
vals.columns = ['_'.join(x) for x in vals.columns.values.reshape(-1)]

# should equal 'label_min' and 'label_max'
for time, label_min, label_max in vals.values:
    plt.annotate(label_min, (time, label_min), xytext=(0, -0.5), color='red')
    plt.annotate(label_max, (time, label_max), xytext=(0, 0.5), color='red')
```